# Split long embed message into pages and can change page with a button using hikari / hikari lightbulb?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots

I've made a bot that will be able to send an `embed message` showing all the variables storing in a `.txt` file, Something like this:

[image: 1]

The code is as follow(just an example):

```py
@plugin.command
@lightbulb.option('type','fruit type' , modifier=lightbulb.OptionModifier.CONSUME_REST)
@lightbulb.command('fruit','available fruit')
@lightbulb.implements(lightbulb.SlashCommand)
async def lan(ctx: lightbulb.Context) -> None:
     if ctx.options.type == 'fru':
        loglist = []
        embed = hikari.Embed(title="Fruits", description="--------------------")

        file = open("fru.txt", "r", encoding="utf8")
        for line in file.readlines():
            l = line.strip()
            loglist.append(l)
            embed.add_field(name="-----", value=" `{0}`".format(l), inline=False)
  
        await ctx.respond(embed)
```

However the embed message gets too long if there are too many variable in the `.txt` file. I'm trying to make that long embed message into pages so it will be easier to read. If it is possible to split that message into pages, Is it possible for me to make like a reaction button with allow user to change pages if they press the button?
Something like this:
[image: 2]

I've been searching for like few hours and can't find similar example for the reaction button using `hikari` nor `hikari lightbulb`. It would be great if someone can help me out.

Note that this bot is coded in python 3.10 and I'm using `hikari` and `hikari-lightbulb` to code the bot.

Comment: That's not discord.py

Comment: Maybe read from a set number of lines per embed. Use a modulo so once you hit the cap, it saves the embed with its current info. Save the embeds in a list and then `send(embeds=embeds_lst)`

Comment: I managed to split the .txt file and the embed message into different pages. Now the problem is to make the page turning button with hikari which I cant find any documents talking about it.

Comment: Maybe this is what you are looking for: https://hikari-lightbulb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_references/utils.html#module-lightbulb.utils.nav